# Dynamically set hibernate.dialect properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have gone through available example and tutorials on how to set `hibernate.dialect` property correctly but found no approach suitable for my situation.

[This](https://medium.com/innomizetech/dynamic-multi-database-application-with-spring-boot-7c61a743e914) tutorial is working best for me, but it lacks the ability to set `hibernate.dialect` property dynamically as I have different types of databases to connect to:

- MS SQL
- Oracle
- H2
- MySQL

With incorrect dialect, my JPA (delete/update) queries fail.

**With below implementation of `@Configuration`, which works perfectly, how may I be able to set `hibernate.dialect` dynamically at runtime for each datasource?**

Thank you in advance.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.example.multidb",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "multiEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "multiTransactionManager"
)
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    private final String PACKAGE_SCAN = "com.example.multidb";    

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.main")
    public DataSource mainDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }    

    @Bean(name = "clientADataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.clienta")
    public DataSource clientADataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "clientBDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource.clientb")
    public DataSource clientBDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "multiRoutingDataSource")
    public DataSource multiRoutingDataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

        targetDataSources.put(DBTypeEnum.MAIN, mainDataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(DBTypeEnum.CLIENT_A, clientADataSource());
        targetDataSources.put(DBTypeEnum.CLIENT_B, clientBDataSource());

        MultiRoutingDataSource multiRoutingDataSource = new MultiRoutingDataSource();

        multiRoutingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(mainDataSource());
        multiRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);        

        return multiRoutingDataSource;
    }   

    @Bean(name = "multiEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean multiEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        em.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());        

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "multiTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager multiTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                multiEntityManager().getObject());        

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dbSessionFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean dbSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(multiRoutingDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_SCAN);
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);        

        //set hibernate.dialect for each datasource

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;` in your classes marked by `@Repository`, can you try to use `entityManager.setProperty(hibernate.dialect, "your dialect");` inside every method where you need to change the dialect? I haven't tested it but I am just throwing out ideas here. This is the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-

Comment: To achieve what you want you must create one class per data source and declare (per class): `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, `DataSource` and the `PlatformTransactionManager`, using different bean names on each of them and setting all the properties you need.
Trying to do everything in a single class won't work as the hibernate properties will be the same for all of the `DataSource`s.

Comment: @Faraz thank you.. I have tried your method and this, unfortunately, did not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a working example for you, I'll describe it here but if you want to jump in the code yourself [it's available at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/so-questions/tree/master/src/main/java/com/marcosbarbero/so/multiple/ds).

In my case, I've created two data sources, one for `User` and another one for `Item`.

Here the entities:

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.user;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private int age;
}
```

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.item;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "item")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

Note, It's important to have distinct packages for each domain.
Then I created the `Repositories`

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.user;

import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.user.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.item;

import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.item.Item;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {
}
```

Nothing special about the repos. Let's move to the final piece, the configuration.

1. I created a `@ConfigurationProperties` class to externalize my configuration, bear with me, I know the naming is not the best :)

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "multi-datasource")
public class MultipleDataSourceProperties {

    private UserDataSourceProperties user = new UserDataSourceProperties();

    private ItemDataSourceProperties item = new ItemDataSourceProperties();

    @Data
    public static class UserDataSourceProperties {
        private HibernateProperties hibernate = new HibernateProperties();
    }

    @Data
    public static class ItemDataSourceProperties {
        private HibernateProperties hibernate = new HibernateProperties();
    }

    @Data
    public static class HibernateProperties {
        private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    }

}
```

We'll see the properties configuration file soon.

2. Now let's create the `DataSource` for the `User`:

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.user",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager"
)
public class UserDataSourceConfig {

    private final MultipleDataSourceProperties properties;

    public UserDataSourceConfig(MultipleDataSourceProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.user");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties.getUser().getHibernate().getProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("multi-datasource.user")
    public DataSource userDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(userEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

The important part for you at this class is the line `em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties.getUser().getHibernate().getProperties());` it's getting the User's Hibernate configuration properties from our `@ConfigurationProperties` class defined above.

3. Now let's do the same for the `Item`:

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.item",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "itemEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "itemTransactionManager"
)
public class ItemDataSourceConfig {

    private final MultipleDataSourceProperties properties;

    public ItemDataSourceConfig(MultipleDataSourceProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean itemEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(itemDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.item");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties.getItem().getHibernate().getProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("multi-datasource.item")
    public DataSource itemDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager itemTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(itemEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

4. The `application.properties`

```
multi-datasource.item.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:spring_jpa_item;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ITEM
multi-datasource.item.username=sa
multi-datasource.item.password=sa

multi-datasource.item.hibernate.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
multi-datasource.item.hibernate.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
multi-datasource.item.hibernate.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
multi-datasource.item.hibernate.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

multi-datasource.user.jdbcUrl=jdbc:h2:mem:spring_jpa_user;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS USER
multi-datasource.user.username=sa
multi-datasource.user.password=sa

multi-datasource.user.hibernate.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
multi-datasource.user.hibernate.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
multi-datasource.user.hibernate.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
multi-datasource.user.hibernate.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

5. Some unit tests

```java
package com.marcosbarbero.so;

import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.item.Item;
import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.entity.user.User;
import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.item.ItemRepository;
import com.marcosbarbero.so.multiple.ds.repository.user.UserRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

@SpringBootTest
public class JPAMultipleDBTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenCreatingUser_thenCreated() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("John");
        user.setEmail("john@test.com");
        user.setAge(20);
        user = userRepository.save(user);

        assertNotNull(userRepository.findById(user.getId()));
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCreatingProduct_thenCreated() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setName("Book");
        item.setId(2);
        item = itemRepository.save(item);

        assertNotNull(itemRepository.findById(item.getId()));
    }
}
```

I think it also worth mentioning, to make it all work I disabled the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`, it's simple as that:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

And again, it all is [available at this GitHub repo](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/so-questions/tree/master/src/main/java/com/marcosbarbero/so/multiple/ds).

Comment: hi @marcos-barbero, thank you for your detailed response and sorry to keep this hanging. Does this mean I have to add `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for each file?

Comment: I would say for each `DataSource`

Comment: hi @marcos-barbero, thank you, i will mark your answer correct. i suppose there is no other way to setup multiple `datasource` other than creating multiple files for each..

Comment: hi @MarcosBarbero I have a similar issue but with a different condition.
I've opened a question, can you take a look if you can suggest a solution?
Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349713/dynamic-dialect-with-hibernate-and-hikari

Comment: Maybe this can help you @effedici https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-databases-with-shared-entity-classes-in-s