# Dynamic dialect with Hibernate and Hikari

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hikaricp, dialect

I am new at Hibernate.
Into my code, the connection to the DB is managed with the Hikari data source.

My code is right now multitenant, but it manages the same hibernate dialect for all tenants.

**Is it possible to create a configuration where each tenant can use a different dialect?**
The type of dialect can be provided as a tenant's property.

---

This is an example of the entityManagerFactory:

```java
     @Bean
     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        Map<String, Object> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put(..., ...);
        jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "myDialect");
        
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {MyEntity.class.getPackage().getName()});
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        return emfBean;
    }
```

---

**Edit**

I was looking to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796798/dynamically-set-hibernate-dialect-properties-in-spring-boot): it suggests to create a duplicated LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for each dialect.
What I do not understand is how can I tell when using one EntityManager (MySQL) and when the other one (Postgres or MsSQL): the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796798/dynamically-set-hibernate-dialect-properties-in-spring-boot) discriminates the entities (each entity has its own DB) but in my case, all entities are on all DBs. Is the tenant that discriminates.

For example: if I create a second instance of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (i.e. msSQLEntityManagerFactory()) with setted the dialect for SQL Server, the application fails to start with:

```
Application failed to start due to an exceptionorg.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available:
 expected single matching bean but found 2: 
msSQLEntityManagerFactory,entityManagerFactory
```

Comment: What do you mean by multitenant code?

Comment: I have an all-in-one architecture: the same instance of the software and the same MySQL can be used with different tenants.
Each tenant is identified by an input parameter which is mapped with a set of configurations (e.g.: the credentials and URL of the tenant's DB).
Each tenant can be used to connect only to its DB (but all tenants are on the same instance of MySQL.

In the future, I would like to have one tenant on MySQL, one on PostgresSQL, and one on SQL server but all inside the same instance of the software.

Comment: sorry , it's still hard for me to grasp my head around multitenant code. Maybe you need to put a dialect inside a properties file, add this properties file as a property source to the spring's environment abstraction and then use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in combination with Value annotation inside your configuration class to set appropriate dialect. Then for each tenant you would have a different properties file.

Comment: I do not understand...how can I set dynamically the dialect?
How can the same instance of the software switch from one to the other?

Comment: when in your program do you have a need to change dialect? If your program works with multiple databases at the same time, then maybe you can declare EntityManager for each with a different dialect.

Comment: yes, I agree.
What I do not understand is how can I tell when using one EntityManager (MySQL) and when the other one (Postgres or MsSQL).

I was looking to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796798/dynamically-set-hibernate-dialect-properties-in-spring-boot)
but is a little bit different because it discriminates the entities (each entity has its own DB) in my case all entities are on all DBs. Is the tenant that discriminate.

Comment: sorry, I can't really think something. To be honest , I still don't quite understand that meaning of tenant and what it means in your case: do you have multiple, let's say, web applications instances that each uses different dialect or inside your application do you have multiple services/layers that each use different dialect?

Comment: I have one instance that should be able to connect to different dialects to execute the operations.

See the "tenant" as an input token that identifies the DB to be used for the operation (and classifies the users). If is tenant=A > go to MySQL, if is tenant=B > to to MsSQL, etc.

 All DBs have the same tables but with different data inside: people of tenant A cannot see the data of people of tenant B.

Comment: @Barracuda I've tried to declare an entity EntityManager for each dialect but it fails with "expected single matching bean but found 2" (see the main message per further details)

Comment: Maybe you can declare your classes to use a Map<String,EntityManager> where map keys are going to be the tokens you are taking about.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to change your services to use maps, declare some other type of Map with services as values, for example.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible as the dialect affects certain quoting rules etc. which you can't just "swap out" at runtime based on a tenant identifier. Just create two persistence units, each pointing to a different data source for every database type. You will have to somehow lookup the appropriate `EntityManager`/`EntityManagerFactory` based on your tenant identifier which makes it a bit harder when you want to use Spring Data JPA as that requires a compilation static name reference for the entity manager factory. Maybe you can create a custom `EntityManagerFactory` that delegates all method calls to the appropriate instance based on the tenant identifier. Overall, this is not so easy and you will probably have to do a lot of trial and error.

IMO it would be better to have a separate application deployment with separate configuration if possible per database type.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to find a solution for this problem.
I managed to get around the problem with the dialects by having an entity manager factory for each dialect (in this case MySQL, Postgres and MS SQL Server).

Create a bean for EntityManagerFactory and return a proxy of that interface and in the handler, based on your logic, you can switch which emf to use to suit the used data source.

I have created a video for this because it seems like there is no documentation online.

[Session Scoped Connection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mcHoaPIiL6w)

It is pretty similar to what you're trying to achieve but in my case the users are providing the credentials, so it's even more complicated.

Comment: Awesome! Your video pointed me in the right direction. But, creating a `EntityManagerFactory` generated some problems with another libs, like Hazelcast. The aproach I used is detailed bellow.

Answer (score 0):

@Tsvetelin answer pointed me on the right direction, but, after applying it, I started having problems with another libs, like Hazelcast that was being user as second level cache.

So, this is what I did:

1. Instead of creating a `EntityManagerFactory` bean, I created a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` that instantiates a `DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

   ```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPackagesToScan(getPackagesToScan());
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return em;

    }
   ```

`getPackagesToScan()` and `additionalProperties()` are functions that reads the parameters that was set by Spring Boot on the application context.

```
private String[] getPackagesToScan() {

    //Check if the defaults packagesToScan needs to be overrided
    String[] packagesToScan = dynamicTenantRoutingPropertiesConfig.getPackagesToScan();

    if (packagesToScan == null) {

        List<String> packageNames = EntityScanPackages.get(context).getPackageNames();
        if (packageNames.isEmpty() && AutoConfigurationPackages.has(context)) {
            packageNames = AutoConfigurationPackages.get(context);
        }

        packagesToScan = packageNames.toArray(new String[0]);

    }

    return packagesToScan;

}

private Properties additionalProperties() {
    
    //jpaProperties is an Autowired bean of type 
    //org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties

    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(jpaProperties.getProperties());
    return properties;
}
```

`DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean` extends `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and overrides `createNativeEntityManagerFactory()`, using the same technique as @tsvetelin-yakimov

```
@Log4j2
@Configurable
public class DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactoryBean extends LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {

        //Obtem a referencia para o Datasource
        AbstractDynamicTenantRoutingDataSource dataSource
                = context.getBean(AbstractDynamicTenantRoutingDataSource.class);

        //Define o Datasource
        this.setDataSource(dataSource);

    }


    @Override
    protected EntityManagerFactory createNativeEntityManagerFactory() throws PersistenceException {

        log.info("(DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactory): Iniciando Proxy...");
        final int hashcode = UUID.randomUUID().toString().hashCode();
        final Map<String, EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactoryMap = new HashMap<>();


        Object emf = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{SessionFactory.class},
                (proxy, method, args) -> {

                    if (method.getName().equals("hashCode")) {
                        return hashcode;
                    }

                    if (method.getName().equals("equals")) {
                        return proxy == args[0];
                    }

                    //Verifica se o DataSource esta preenchido
                    if (this.getDataSource() == null)
                        throw new PersistenceException("O DataSource não pode ser nulo");

                    //Verifica se ja temos o EntityManager para esse Datasource
                    String currentDriver = ((AbstractDynamicTenantRoutingDataSource) this.getDataSource()).resolveCurrentDriver();
                    EntityManagerFactory instance = entityManagerFactoryMap.get(currentDriver);

                    if (instance == null) {

                        //Obtem o dialeto
                        Dialect dialect = ((AbstractDynamicTenantRoutingDataSource) this.getDataSource()).resolveDialect(currentDriver);

                        log.info(
                                "(DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactory): Iniciando EntityManagerFactory para Driver {} Dialeto {}...",
                                currentDriver,
                                dialect
                        );

                        instance = this.createEntityManagerFactory(
                                dialect
                        );

                        entityManagerFactoryMap.put(
                                currentDriver,
                                instance
                        );

                    }

                    log.debug(
                            "(DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactory): Retornando EntityManagerFactory para Driver {}...",
                            currentDriver
                    );
                    return method.invoke(instance);

                }
        );

        log.info("(DynamicTenantEntityManagerFactory): Iniciando Proxy... Concluido!");
        return (SessionFactory) emf;

    }

    private EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(Dialect dialect) {

        EntityManagerFactory factory = super.createNativeEntityManagerFactory();
        factory
                .getProperties()
                .put("hibernate.dialect", dialect.getClass().getName());

        return factory;

    }

}
```